# Alsa Pulse Audio cannot open audio device pulse (No such file or directory) pulse: Input/output error

Tags: linux, centos, alsa, ffmpeg, pulseaudio

I'm trying to stream my Gnome Desktop I installed on my OpenVZ VPS Server, and I'm not trying to run this from SSH, but the terminal inside the GNOME desktop,

I know it probably doesn't have a sound card, but it's not like i'm trying to play the sound, I just want to route it to the stream.

Inside my PulseAudio Volume Control
[image: volume control]

Here is how it looks like when I attempt to stream it.
[image: ffmpeg]

More stuff I tried more errors happened here
[image: more errors about alsa, soundcards]

Here is when I run the `pacmd list-source-outputs`

```
[removed@removed ~]$ pacmd list-source-outputs
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 2 source outputs(s) available.
    index: 0
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: DONT_MOVE 
    state: RUNNING
    source: 0 <auto_null.monitor>
    current latency: 3.08 ms
    requested latency: 20.00 ms
    sample spec: float32le 1ch 25Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    resample method: peaks
    owner module: 6
    client: 4 <PulseAudio Volume Control>
    properties:
        media.name = "Peak detect"
        application.name = "PulseAudio Volume Control"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "16"
        application.id = "org.PulseAudio.pavucontrol"
        application.icon_name = "audio-card"
        application.version = "0.9.10"
        application.process.id = "997"
        application.process.user = "removed_for_stackexchange(wasn't root)"
        application.process.host = "removed_for_stackexchange"
        application.process.binary = "pavucontrol"
        window.x11.display = ":1.0"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "27be3273f5d5332051ccdc3100000002"
        application.process.session_id = "27be3273f5d5332051ccdc3100000002-1394085585.776225-694791372"
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-id:org.PulseAudio.pavucontrol"
    index: 1
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: DONT_MOVE 
    state: RUNNING
    source: 0 <auto_null.monitor>
    current latency: 3.11 ms
    requested latency: 20.00 ms
    sample spec: float32le 1ch 25Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    resample method: peaks
    owner module: 6
    client: 4 <PulseAudio Volume Control>
    direct on input: 2
    properties:
        media.name = "Peak detect"
        application.name = "PulseAudio Volume Control"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "16"
        application.id = "org.PulseAudio.pavucontrol"
        application.icon_name = "audio-card"
        application.version = "0.9.10"
        application.process.id = "997"
        application.process.user = "removed_for_stackexchange(wasn't root)"
        application.process.host = "removed_for_stackexchange"
        application.process.binary = "pavucontrol"
        window.x11.display = ":1.0"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "27be3273f5d5332051ccdc3100000002"
        application.process.session_id = "27be3273f5d5332051ccdc3100000002-1394085585.776225-694791372"
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-id:org.PulseAudio.pavucontrol"
```

More information about sink i'm using

```
[removed@removed ~]$ pacmd list-sinks
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1000
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 3.49 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 3 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 3
    configured latency: 20.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 10000.00 ms
    module: 9
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***(hopefully) IMPROVED CODE AT BOTTOM***

Reading the script provided in your own answer, I've reached the following conclusions about your solution. Please correct me on any/all mistakes I might have made.

You append an `xwininfo $GAME_WINDOW`-specific dataset to a `tmp`file dump after specifying `$GAME_WINDOW`'s geometry via `wmctl`. Before initiating the dump you effectively truncate your `tmp`file to 0-bytes with `rm -f` which presumably occurs only once per session either because the stream is session-specific or to avoid the `tmp`file growing too large, though, again, I'm presuming both. I base the above conclusions on these three lines:

```
> rm -f twitch_tmp 2> /dev/null
> wmctrl -r "$GAME_WINDOW" -e 0, 411,51,160,144
> xwininfo -name "$GAME_WINDOW" >> twitch_tmp
```

While I'm not intimately familiar with either `wmctl` or `xwininfo` I do know that they're common *xorg* utilities for automating various *X* window behaviors. I'm assuming you're streaming that dataset just to keep up with any changes as they might occur so `ffmpeg` can do the right thing with its transcode rather than actually pumping the actual graphic/sound source data through the following two *environment* variables as I doubt very seriously the latter behavior would work for any more than a few seconds if at all:

```
> TOPXY=$(cat twitch_tmp | grep -oEe 'Corners:\s+\+[0-9]+\+[0-9]+' | grep -oEe '[0-9]+\+[0-9]+' | sed -e 's/\+/,/' )
> INRES=$(cat twitch_tmp | grep -oEe 'geometry [0-9]+x[0-9]+' | grep -oEe '[0-9]+x[0-9]+')
```

Here you:

- Open two `$(command substitution)` subshells, one each for `$TOPXY` and `$INRES` value assignments.

For `$TOPXY` you:

- Con`cat`enate your `tmp`file with `stdin` and anonymously `|pipe` the results to `grep`'s `stdin` which then ...
- `oEe` Omits any line and any portion of any line not thereby omitted which does not contain the string:

  - "*Corners:*" followed by ...
  - at `+` least one `\s` whitespace character, then ...
  - a `\+` literal plus sign, then ...
  - at `+` least one `[0-9]` digit ...
  - another `\+` literal plus ...
  - and, finally, at least `+` one more `[0-9]` digit ...
- The results are anonymously `|piped` to another instance of `grep` which subsequently `-oEe` omits everything before your first captured `[0-9]` digit then anonymously `|pipe` its results to ...
- `sed` which `tr`ansforms all literal `\+` pluses it receives to `,` commas and dumps to its `stdout` which is ...
- finally captured and stored in `$TOPXY` via the `$(command substituted)` subshell variable assignment.

The process for `$INRES` appears much the same, if a little less complex.

Most noteworthy to me is that the entire `tmp`file is con`cat`enated at least **twice** for every invocation, which is not to mention all of the `|pipes`. Probably there are a lot of ways to do this, but I can't imagine this would be among the better of them.

After this you invoke `ffmpeg` referencing the two variables above and various other options including other environment variables you've also specified:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i $DISPLAY+$TOPXY \
    -f pulse -i default \
    -vcodec libx264 -preset $PRESET -crf 30 -x264opts keyint=50:min-keyint=20 -s $INRES \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ab $AUDIO_BITRATE -ar $AUDIO_RATE_HZ \
    -threads 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -f flv "rtmp://$SERVER.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
```

***PROBABLY MORE DIRECT***

What follows involves no `tmp`files, a single `|pipe`, calls only a single invocation of `sed` and a single subshell `command substitution` for parsing your geometry settings, and is contained in a single function. All of the environment variables are defined in `here-documents` streamed to its `stdin` and are therefore effectively locally scoped. They are also defined via `parameter-substitution` and are therefore configurable. For instance to alter the value of `$FPS` for a single invocation you need only do:

```
% FPS=28 desk_stream
```

For what it's worth, though, I still think `vlc` would make a much better option.

```
desk_stream() { sed -rn '\
    /.*((Corners:|geometry)\s*\+*([x|+|0-9]*\+)).*/{\
        s//\3/;\ 
            /X/s/.*/\
                    INRES="&";/p;\
                s/(.*)\+(.*)\+$/\
                    DISPLAY='"${DISPLAY}"'"+\1,\2,";/p;\
    };$a\. 0<&3 /dev/stdin\n' | . /dev/stdin
} <<FFOPTS 3<<-\FFCMD
${FPS="15"}                                    # target FPS
${PRESET="ultrafast"}                    # one of the many FFMPEG preset on (k)ubuntu found in /usr/share/ffmpeg
${THREADS="0"}                 #0 autostarts threads based on cpu cores.
${AUDIO_BITRATE="1k"}               #Audio bitrate to 96k
${AUDIO_RATE_HZ ="44100"}       #Audio rate 44100 hz
${GAME_WINDOW="MYGAMETEST"}
${STREAM_KEY=live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx}
${SERVER="live-jfk"}    # NY server
$(wmctrl -r "$GAME_WINDOW" -e 0, 411,51,160,144 &&\
      xwininfo -name "$GAME_WINDOW")
FFOPTS
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i $DISPLAY \
        -f pulse -i default \
        -vcodec libx264 -preset $PRESET -crf 30 -x264opts keyint=50:min-keyint=20 -s $INRES \
        -acodec libmp3lame -ab $AUDIO_BITRATE -ar $AUDIO_RATE_HZ \
        -threads 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -f flv "rtmp://$SERVER.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
FFCMD
```

Answer (score 1):

So you've definitely got pulseaudio installed, but you are apparently missing the ALSA pulseaudio emulation drivers. Pulseaudio is interfaced by client apps in a lot of different ways, but a common one is for the applications to address ALSA and pulseaudio to intercept. Alsamixer evern works this way on a properly configured system. [Here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) is a very useful page for understanding the way pulseaudio works. In particular, it has this to say on *module-alsa-sink*:

> You should (almost) never have to load this module manually.

You might be interested in the module a couple lines up there, *module-pipe-{sink,source}*:

> Provides a simple test {sink,source} that {writes,reads} the audio data {to,from} a FIFO...

To that end, if you've got VLC, or can get it, you might try streaming  with it:

```
pacmd list-source-outputs
```

should contain an output address something like what I've pasted in below for your dummy source:

```
cvlc pulse://alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor \
    --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2}:\
     standard{access=http,dst=0.0.0.0:8080/pc.mp3}' &
```

Oh, and you might also have some interest in *pacat* and you've probably already got it. It's the single executable that both *parec* and *paplay* link to.

A little more on Pulse/ALSA (though they're documentation is pretty good on this):

Pulseaudio attempts to imitate ALSA for any application that hasn't yet been updated to interface it. Basically the theory goes that if an application isn't equipped to do dbus it with pulse, pulse will middleman ALSA anyway via the *module-alsa-sink* plugin interface I mentioned before. In fact, the same is true for OSS and Esound and their respective modules if they should be required.

But maybe you're overthinking this - the simplest sound streaming can be accomplished with mkfifo, or even just cat, should you desire. Depending on your bandwidth and latency requirements netcat could be pretty useful here. You could also look in to Sox - it offers an interface similar to pacat.

What is your linux distribution? I understand its in a container, but verifying you've updated all relevant packages is probably called for here, especially if pulse isn't running. Try this:

```
pulseaudio --start
```

If it runs, try this for maybe a better hint at what your source might be:

```
pacmd list-source-outputs | grep 'source:'
```

Comment: pacat `Connection failure: Connection refused`  pacmd `No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.` lol who knows why the sound sliders move. Actually it used to work.. must of crashed, how do I make pulseaudio a service? or i should just restart the server

Comment: Do I need VLC? can I set it up with ffmpeg some how? I been researching for hours now best thing I found was to use jack-capture to dump speakers to file. pacmd idea sounds better if I can link it up with ffmpeg

Comment: What is `ALSA pulseaudio emulation drivers` I can't find these is there a yum command for this?

Comment: added lots of outputs for `pacmd list-sinks` and `pacmd list-source-outputs` in question

Comment: I need from research to add to ffmpeg `-f pulse -i "$INPUT_SINK"`  what is the `$INPUT_SINK`? I tried just 0 from the `index: 0` above in `pacmd list-sinks` I get `[pulse @ 0x20a4c00] pa_simple_new failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: `parec` starts typing crazy letters in the console, I guess thats the sound wave lol? anyway I can just link that `parec` to `ffmpeg`

Comment: parec records audio - to somehwere. It sounds like you got your stream - those crazy letters were most likely the bits of the audio stream flooding your console. A !! | nc target.domain $PORT is probably all you need, now.

Comment: I'm trying to stream video and audio as one package over rtmp thats why I have to use ffmpeg.. I almost got it working a few minutes ago, but I broke it again I found a script `ffgrabaudio` but i can't combine it all together.. I don't know where to put the `sink name i guess?` in the `ffmpeg`

Comment: Using the script `ffgrabaudio.sh -g system` this what happened to my Output Device it changed names.. and still works.. look at screenshot http://i.imgur.com/0GjpxJz.png the good thing about this script it also hooks up to the game i'm trying to stream not the whole system by window name, it creates a bunch of playback's with combobox's i'll show you screenshot of that soon

Comment: That's just pavucontrol - it won't do much for you here. It is handy for adjusting volumes on loaded sink/source modules, but it won't set them up for you. paprefs used to work for gui config of pulse modules - but it doesn't  any updated system anymore. I forgot what broke it, but maybe it has something to do with this other issue you're having? Have you updated your packages? About ffmpeg - maybe I'm wrong, but I've always considered it to be more of a codec than anything else - are you trying to set pulseaudio to serve its stream? Anything with networking function can handle that.

Comment: yes i want pulseaudio to be ffmpegs audio stream `pacmd list-source-outputs` `Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 0 source outputs(s) available.` When I open the `pavucontrol` then i get 2 source outputs.

Comment: But `pacmd list-sinks` even with pavucontrol closed shows 1 sink which is auto_null.. it has state: `RUNNING` `device.description = "Dummy Output"` `device.icon_name ="audio-card"` maybe thats what I need to link somehow

Comment: The ouputs are not available because you havent configured them. Pulse uses its own, weirdy private udev to automatically detect and configure available resources on load but if there are zero devices available I can't imagine it would be very effective. You need to setup a FIFO or some other target, load the appropriate pulse modules then connect ffmpeg and pulse as necessary.

Comment: There is few people who I've seen on random forums that said they managed to achieve this, since I don't have a sound-card on this VPS I need some kind of `Virtual Audio Cable` almost everyone else said nothing you can do to get this to work.

Comment: Yeah, on that page I linked you to you'll see that module-source-null is configured to be available by default when nothing else is. Pulse always keeps at least one open, and if nothing else, it's going to be null.

Comment: A "Virtual Audio Cable" is a pipe - nothing more. It is a buffered connection over which bits flow. cat /dev/audio | remote:/dev/audio is a virtual audio cable. pacat | nc is a virtual audio cable.

Comment: I don't understand all this module source null,sink stuff at all. How would I begin by setting it up? You mentioned I need those Emulation drivers where do I get them any rpm for them? I couldn't compile the asla_driver kernel_headers were half corrupt. I thought I needed one of those snd_dummy so I could modprobe it.

Comment: `cat: /dev/audio: No such file or directory` Guess I don't have that audio haha.. pacat i'll try that out.  `cat pacat` in ffmpeg somewhere? nvm it's already a `cat` on it's own, you said it's a recorder so it's recording the current sound then

Comment: You may need those at that. They're just another module though - like I said, they are what pulse uses to imitate alsa. That webpage with the lists of modules I linked you to has a LOT to say on the subject.

Comment: No such file. Exactly - that would be a special device file installed by udev upon detection of audio hardware. Any device file setup without it would need to be something you configure. Besides, I don't even think that's a standard designation - I was just using it as an example.

Comment: I really don't know what to do next.. reading that documentation probably won't get me anywhere. So far all I got to work with is pacat which probably sends out some unknown audio format which I have to somehow run simultaneously with ffmpeg so probably have to dump it to disk somewhere and load it with ffmpeg. I can't configure anything I don't how and no sound cards on this vps either. I just want the audio to instantly get streamed without processing or anything like direct link game -> to ffmpeg, also I'll probably try vlc.. don't know how good that is.. but it's bulky 100 Megs..

Comment: Opps, clicked the chat thing by accident, I just wanted to post this link http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=110440 is that something the documentation says I need to do?

Comment: What documentation? Oh, well, it certainly won't get you anywhere if you don't read it. I did already give you the copy of what I used to pipe sound around as I like - the cvlc command up top. What kind of "unknown audio format?" Of course, if you were curious, you could try pacat --list-audio-formats...

Comment: This one http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/ Okay I started to read it.. I think I need the `module-tunnel-{sink,source}`

Comment: I've just ran this `pacmd load-module module-http-protocol-tcp`  here is the information http://camspark.com:4714/ I hope this won't get me hacked.

Comment: You need to turn that off. Just use the simple FIFO one. Or pacat. Seriously. Pacat and your dummy output will work, I think.

Comment: For traversing the network just pipe it through a command interface with which you're familiar - do you use ssh? pacat | ssh me@mybox 'paplay'

Comment: Lol how can I play it off ssh, I am using windows on my computer, the server uses centos 6.3

Comment: I'm on my laptop - I don't even know if it has sound configured either, never checked. BUT it did attempt to send me a file (the pipe-stream) which I cancelled immediately to come here to tell you to turn that off. I'm sorry, man, but I don't have anymore advice.

Comment: I understand, i'm not a linux guy I'm more of a java/html/jquery guy this is all very complicated to me, but i'll keep trying thanks for all the help.

Comment: Pulseaudio has a lot of windows applications. They have a windows sound server. They have pacat,paplay,parec. Sox will play a pcm stream, or oga or whatever - it is windows and and linux friendly. There are numerous ssh servers and clients for Windows.

Comment: And last, vlc is EASY. It is the video lan client and has been for close to a couple decades now, I think. I run that one command on my box and connect to it from phones, other computers, whatever. Piece of cake.

Comment: It's not even broadcasting any sound. Can you just tell me can I do this without a sound card? here are my results http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6bc3c5e6cb32f5a959b153324ccb0c81307ab372 my exact question here: http://superuser.com/questions/718267/how-can-i-use-a-virtual-sound-card-without-the-hardware

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself,
This below works perfect even without a sound card on your VPS, it streams desktop both audio and video.

```
FPS="15"                                    # target FPS
PRESET="ultrafast"                    # one of the many FFMPEG preset on (k)ubuntu found in /usr/share/ffmpeg
THREADS="0"                 #0 autostarts threads based on cpu cores.
AUDIO_BITRATE="1k"               #Audio bitrate to 96k
AUDIO_RATE_HZ ="44100"       #Audio rate 44100 hz
GAME_WINDOW="MYGAMETEST"
STREAM_KEY=live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
SERVER="live-jfk"    # NY server

rm -f twitch_tmp 2> /dev/null
wmctrl -r "$GAME_WINDOW" -e 0, 411,51,160,144
xwininfo -name "$GAME_WINDOW" >> twitch_tmp
TOPXY=$(cat twitch_tmp | grep -oEe 'Corners:\s+\+[0-9]+\+[0-9]+' | grep -oEe '[0-9]+\+[0-9]+' | sed -e 's/\+/,/' )
INRES=$(cat twitch_tmp | grep -oEe 'geometry [0-9]+x[0-9]+' | grep -oEe '[0-9]+x[0-9]+')

ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i $DISPLAY+$TOPXY \
             -f pulse -i default \
             -vcodec libx264 -preset $PRESET -crf 30 -x264opts keyint=50:min-keyint=20 -s $INRES \
             -acodec libmp3lame -ab $AUDIO_BITRATE -ar $AUDIO_RATE_HZ \
             -threads 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
             -f flv "rtmp://$SERVER.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
```